# How does the type conversion work for a struct with a unsized field?

Tags: rust

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Piece<T: ?Sized = [u8]> {
    index: [u8; 4],
    begin: [u8; 4],
    block: T,
}

impl Piece {
    const PIECE_LEAD: usize = std::mem::size_of::<Piece<()>>();
    pub fn ref_from_bytes(data: &[u8]) -> Option<&Self> {
        if data.len() < Self::PIECE_LEAD {
            return None;
        }
        let n = data.len();
        // NOTE: The slicing here looks really weird. The reason we do it is because we need the
        // length part of the fat pointer to Piece to hold the length of _just_ the `block` field.
        // And the only way we can change the length of the fat pointer to Piece is by changing the
        // length of the fat pointer to the slice, which we do by slicing it. We can't slice it at
        // the front (as it would invalidate the ptr part of the fat pointer), so we slice it at
        // the back!
        let piece = &data[..n - Self::PIECE_LEAD] as *const [u8] as *const Piece;
        // Safety: Piece is a POD with repr(c) and repr(packed), _and_ the fat pointer data length
        // is the length of the trailing DST field (thanks to the PIECE_LEAD offset).
        Some(unsafe { &*piece })
    }
}
```

I want to know why, after the type conversion, the length of the block field is the same as the length of the slice reference before the conversion.

Comment: This code is unsound.

Comment: Why won't it? What did you expect?

Comment: I don't know if this is what was meant by "unsound", but this definitely has alignment problems if T ever becomes a slice of a type larger than `u8`.  For example, this will SIGBUS on some systems (e.g., SPARC) if T is `[u32]` and `data` is not 4-byte aligned.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 
Assuming T is always u8 and i have type cast like this: 
`let v = vec![0u8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]; let p = unsafe { &*(v.as_slice() as *const [u8] as *const P) };`.
In this case length of `p.block` will be `12` and `p.block` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...random_data]` which is out of bounds. I want to know why the length of p.block is 12.

Comment: @bk2204 That's not what I meant: it is UB _currently_, because it creates a reference but then accesses it out of bounds.

Comment: Why not? Casting leaves the metadata unchanged. It was 12, it will still be 12.